# Overriding the alert method in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to **override the Alert method**. Alert should have what is currently + **displaying a graphic** with or without text.

```
public IDisposable Alert(string message, string title = null, string okText = null)
{
    if(!SingletonsManager.Instance.RuntimeManagerInstance.AppInBackground)
    {
        return UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(message, title, okText);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Comment: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use a package, like [Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) to achieve this, without custom renderers, it is impossible to add an Image to the default AlertDialog, which will limit you.

Using Popup Plugin, you just have to add it to your solution, initialize in both iOS and Android:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
      Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();

      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
      LoadApplication (new App ());
      return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
    }
}
```

Create a Popup Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyPopupPage">

    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <Label
            Text="Test"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

And, to show in your page:

```
    await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page);
```